# Toolbar: background of the bottom menu

Tags: android, toolbar

I'm trying to deploy Toolbar in my application. I can change the primary color but it doesn't involve on the bottom menu like on the attached screen.

I tried already to use the generated resources but without any result (it works only if I use the old ActionBar).

How can I change the background color of the bottom menu on Android 4.1.2 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. If somebody will search the answer you can use mine experience. What you have to do is just overriding style attributes from appcompat_v7/res/values/themes_base.xml

```
<...>
<item name="panelMenuListWidth">@dimen/abc_panel_menu_list_width</item>
<item name="panelMenuListTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu</item>
<item name="panelBackground">@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult</item>
<item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_light</item>
<...>
```

To change the background color of the bottom menu use panelBackground.